# python: how to remove time from date for np array

Tags: python, date

I have the code below which I want to keep the date itself only.

```
>>> date = q_data.Date
>>> dt = np.array(date)
>>> dt
array(['2017-02-14 09:00:00', '2017-02-15 09:00:00', '2017-02-16 09:00:00',       '2017-02-17 09:00:00', '2017-02-20 09:00:00', '2017-02-21 09:00:00',       '2017-02-22 09:00:00', '2017-02-23 09:00:00', '2017-02-24 09:00:00',       '2017-02-28 09:00:00', '2017-03-01 09:00:00', '2017-03-02 09:00:00',       '2017-03-03 09:00:00', '2017-03-06 09:00:00', '2017-03-07 09:00:00',       '2017-03-08 09:00:00', '2017-03-09 09:00:00', '2017-03-10 09:00:00',] dtype=object)
```

I want it to have the following:
`array(['2017-02-14','2017-02-15',....]dtyepe=object)`

`dt.date()` return `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: just do some basic string processing: `[d.split()[0] for d in dates]`.

Comment: Or just take the first 10 characters of each string: `map(lambda x: x[:10], dates)`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your input (`date`) is a series of string representations of date and time, with a space between the date and the time.  If the format is **guaranteed** to be consistent with what you showed here, then you could use a list comprehension:

```
date = [x.split()[0] for x in date]
dt = np.array(date)
```

Alternatively, if `date` were a series of `datetime` objects, you could use:

```
date = [x.date().isoformat() for x in date]
dt = np.array(date)
```

**Edit**: If I'm understanding correctly that this is a Pandas dataframe with a single column, containing string representations of dates and times, the following would be one way to retain the `dtype=object` property:

```
def trim_to_date(s): 
     return s.split()[0]
date = date[0].apply(trim_to_date) 
dt = np.array(date))
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, Date is in pandas dataframe. Then it is convert to numpy array with `dt = np.array(date)`. The `dtype=object` need to keep.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
from dateutil import *

arr = np.array(['2017-02-14 09:00:00', '2017-02-15 09:00:00', '2017-02-16 09:00:00'])

np.array([parser.parse(i).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in arr])

# array(['2017-02-14', '2017-02-15', '2017-02-16'],
#       dtype='<U10')
```